# Removing the initial \ of a command name, for use with \csname

Tags: macros, csname

The TeXBook has the following text on page 40 (emphasis added)

> Conversely, you can go from a list of character tokens to a control sequence by saying `\csname⟨tokens⟩\endcsname`. The tokens that appear in this construction between `\csname` and `\endcsname` may include other control sequences, as long as those control sequences ultimately expand into characters instead of TEX primitives; the final characters can be of any category, not necessarily letters. For example, `\csname TeX\endcsname` is essentially the same as `\TeX`; but `\csname\TeX\endcsname` is illegal, because `\TeX` expands into tokens containing the `\kern` primitive. **Furthermore, `\csname\string\TeX\endcsname` will produce the unusual
> control sequence `\\TeX`, i.e., the token [`\TeX`], which you can’t ordinarily write.**

Unfortunately it doesn't say what you can do about that last point, if you want to remove the initial `\` and end up with the control sequence `\TeX`. This question is about how to do that.

### Why do I want that?

I'd like to create a "factory" command that dynamically generates several new commands. The following works:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myfactory}{m m}{
    \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{m}{A command has been created with argument ``#2'' and called with argument ``##1''}
}

\myfactory{\mycommand}{Hello}

\begin{document}

\mycommand{World!}

\end{document}
```

it gives the following output as expected:

[image]

However, if I change the factory to also make a "special" version of the command, then it fails

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myfactory}{m m}{
    \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{m}{A command has been created with argument ``#2'' and called with argument ``##1''}
    \NewDocumentCommand{#1special}{m}{A `special' command has been created with argument ``#2'' and called with argument ``##1''}
}

\myfactory{\mycommand}{Hello}

\begin{document}

\mycommand{World!}
\mycommandspecial{Special world!}

\end{document}
```

The error message is the following, which seems very reasonable

```
./newcommand name mangling.tex:8: LaTeX cmd Error: First argument of '\NewDocum
entCommand' must be a command.
```

So then I can try to generate the command name using `\csname` and `\endcsname`, but the following fails for the reason described above:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myfactory}{m m}{
    \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{m}{A command has been created with argument ``#2'' and called with argument ``##1''}
    \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname #1special\endcsname{m}{A `special' command has been created with argument ``#2'' and called with argument ``##1''}
}

\myfactory{\mycommand}{Hello}

\begin{document}

\mycommand{World!}

\mycommandspecial{Special world!}

\end{document}
```

Here we get the error

```
./newcommand name mangling.tex:13: Undefined control sequence.
l.13 \mycommandspecial
                      {Special world!}
```

which I'm guessing is because it actually defines a command called `\\mycommandspecial`, which there's no normal way to call.

On the other hand, the following *does* work, but it's a bit annoying because the user has to call it like `\myfactory{mycommand}{Hello}` instead of `\myfactory{\mycommand}{Hello}`, and I'd prefer the latter.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myfactory}{m m}{
    \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname #1\endcsname{m}{A command has been created with argument ``#2'' and called with argument ``##1''}
    \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname #1special\endcsname{m}{A `special' command has been created with argument ``#2'' and called with argument ``##1''}
}

\myfactory{mycommand}{Hello}

\begin{document}

\mycommand{World!}

\mycommandspecial{Special world!}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define your `\csstring` command. It's already there with LuaTeX; if not defined, it will use `\cs_to_str:N` from `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\ProvideExpandableDocumentCommand{\csstring}{m}{\cs_to_str:N #1}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\myfactory}{m m}{%
  \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{m}{%
    A command has been created with argument ``#2'' and called with argument ``##1''%
  }%
  \ExpandArgs{c}\NewDocumentCommand{\csstring #1special}{m}{%
    A `special' command has been created with argument ``#2'' and called with argument ``##1''%
  }%
}

\myfactory{\mycommand}{Hello}

\begin{document}

\mycommand{World!}

\mycommandspecial{Special world!}

\end{document}
```

For the “special” command you need `\ExpandArgs{c}` that will jump over the following tokens and build a command name from the braced group that follows. The construction is equivalent to

```
\expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname \csstring#1special\endcsname{m}{...}
```

but more readable.

Don't forget to protect endlines.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using LuaTeX, you can use the `\csstring` primitive instead of `\string`, which leaves the initial backslash out.

With other engines, you can easily define `\csstring` yourself:

```tex
\def\gobble#1{}
\def\csstring{\expandafter\gobble\string}
```

This works because `\string` expands to a series of category-12 tokens (i.e. nonletter printable characters), from which you can discard the first after expansion.

**Edit:** as pointed out below, this macro will not work if `\escapechar` is set to `-1` or `32`. Just to be complete, the following will work in those cases, too:

```tex
\def\gobble#1{} \def\gobbletwo#1#2{}
\def\csstring{%
    \ifnum-1=\escapechar \expandafter\gobbletwo \else
    \ifnum32=\escapechar \expandafter\expandafter
        \expandafter\gobbletwo\fi\fi
    \expandafter\gobble\string}
```

Setting `\escapechar=-1` provides another way of getting around your problem, and is used in e.g. plain.tex’s `\newif` macro.

Comment: That assumes that the escape char is printable, is not a space, etc. You can do it, of course: see the `expl3` function `\cs_to_str:N`.

Comment: Whatever the escape char is, it will be returned with category code 12, ensuring that `\gobble` can see and eat it. So this does not matter.

Comment: That said, I would *love* seeing an example of a nonprintable escape char in actual use.

Comment: No, if it's a space it will be catcode 10. You can have a non-printable escape char readily: it's used for example by the NFSS code in LaTeX.

Comment: @renkema no, apart from space, if it is -1 then no character is added so you will gobble the first character of the name

Comment: Ah indeed, it seems that both `\spacechar=32` and `\spacechar=-1` will break this macro. Thanks for pointing that out.